# Latin characters display ? objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, utf

I am making a call to get a JSON response like this:

```
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:serviceRequest returningResponse:&httpResponse error:nil ];
NSString *returnString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

However, when I print the string using NSLog:

```
Emiratos �rabes Unidos
```

When I convert it to NSData like this:

```
NSData *jsonData = [returnString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray * response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
```

It turns it to be (when I retrieve the value from the array):

```
Emiratos \Ufffdrabes Unidos
```

And when I put it in a label it displays it like this:

```
Emiratos �rabes Unidos
```

I would like to display in a label like this:

```
Emiratos Árabes Unidos
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Looks like you're not getting the data you expect from the service. Have you inspected the data itself before doing any kind of decoding?

Comment: Can you please explain your comment? I think that I retrieve it fine, it just doesn't encode it properly

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be unclear. You're expecting the value `\U00C1` at that point in the string, but it looks like you might be receiving `\UFFFF` instead -- the service is just not sending what you expect, perhaps. If you look at the raw data before you decode it to a string, you can confirm that.

Comment: I also think that is a encoding problem in the server. I have developed from server spanish apps and I don't have problems. What happen when you see this json in a browser?

Comment: @JoshCaswell the url data looks to me like numbers. how can I see it as a String if I don't decode it?

Comment: @RoxeeMan in the browser I also get it as name: "Emiratos �rabes Unidos"

Comment: Have you implemented the web service?

Comment: No. I am the developer of the app. Not the BE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be this line:

```
NSString *returnString = 
    [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData 
                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You are assuming that the data is a string encoded as UTF8. But apparently it isn't. Therefore you're seeing the "replacement character" (codepoint U+FFFD) at this point.

You'll need to find out what encoding is actually being used. You can probably just experiment with other encodings. Alternatively, use NSLog to look at the data; an NSData object is logged as a sequence of hex bytes, so by looking at the bytes in that position, and by looking up various encodings on the Internet, you may be able to deduce what encoding is being used here.

(But if you use NSLog and you actually see FFFD at this point, then you've had it; the server itself is supplying the bad data and there's nothing you can do about it, as the good data is lost before you can get at it.)